# how and when HashMap initialize entrySet and add value into it

Tags: java, hashmap

I find a very magic thing, the simple code as below:

```
public class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("a", "aa");
        System.out.println("end");
    }
}
```

after invoke

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

[image: the state of map object]
the field variable **entrySet** is not *null*, that is to say it have been initialize.

---

Then this is my **first** question, when the **entrySet** has been initialized?
it seemed the relevant code should be in the construct of *HashMap*, but below is the source code of this constructor

```
 public HashMap() {
    this.loadFactor = DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR; // all other fields defaulted
}
```

it seemed there dont exist code which initialize **entrySet**.

and thing go on.
after invoke

```
map.put("a","aa")
```

the content of field variable *table* and *entrySet* as below shot.
 [image]
Then this is my second problem: when add this value into entrySet?
It seemed that it should be the *put* method achieve these thing.
and below is *put* method.

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    return putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, true);
}
```

it invoke *putVal* method and below is some code of *putVal*

```
final V putVal(...) {
    ....
    tab[i] = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
    ....
    ++modCount;//after invoke this the entrySet is still empty
    if (++size > threshold)
        resize();//this has not been executed
    afterNodeInsertion(evict);//I debug several times, sometimes before invoke this the entrySet has an Element and sometimes
    return null;
}
```

after invoke

```
 ++modCount;
```

the *entrySet* is empty
and before invoke

```
 afterNodeInsertion(evict);
```

the entrySet has a element.
but it seemed the code between these two line has nothing with *entrySet*.
I think maybe there exist several threads operate *entrySet* then I write a small tool with *jvm_ti* to print the threadID which invoke the class below package *java.util* and find there is only one thread.

Then what I miss? Does there exist issue at process of debug? Wish I have describe my problem clearly and everything would be appreciate.

**add:**   my java version is *1.8.0_77* and eclipse version is *4.6.1* and *4.5.1*

Comment: Why does this matter? How is it affecting the contract?

Comment: @SkinnyJ it doesnt matter, but I want to know the actually detail and encounter some question.

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint to the method entrySet() in HashMap?  I assume the entry set is initialized there.  If you put the breakpoint there and the thread pauses, you can see the stack trace of the code that calls this method.

Comment: @ toongeorges  yes, I do add a breakpoint at this method, and it tell me before execute `HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();` this method has been invoke, I think this should the jvm do sth. And after that this method has not been invoked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is your debugger that fools you. The debugger view calls `toString()` which in fact calls `entrySet()` (see `AbstractMap.toString()`). That is why the `entrySet` was already initialized, when you looked at it.

If you look in there via reflection utils, e.g. with the following code:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

Field entrySetField = HashMap.class.getDeclaredField("entrySet");
entrySetField.setAccessible(true);
Object entrySet = entrySetField.get(map);
System.out.println("entrySet = " + entrySet);
System.out.println("map.toString() = " + map.toString());
entrySet = entrySetField.get(map);
System.out.println("entrySet = " + entrySet);
```

you get the following output:

```
entrySet = null
map.toString() = {}
entrySet = []
```

As you can see: entrySet in fact is still `null` if no `toString()` is called and gets initialized after it.

The same applies to your second question. If you look at the values "reflectively":

```
// Starting from where my entrySet is still null
map.put("key", "value");
entrySet = entrySetField.get(map);
System.out.println("entrySet = " + entrySet);
```

you get, as expected:

```
entrySet = null
```

Comment: This is exactly what happens while debugging, good point with AbstractMap!

Comment: @Roland wonderful, but there still has an extra issue, if I use `map.toString()` in the second case, it will print *[key=value]* rather than *[]*.In *entrySet* method it just new an *EntrySet* Object through the default constructor So I dont know when the element was inserted into *entrySet*.

Comment: Do you mean, how the entrySet knows about the values? If so: `EntrySet` is an inner class and so knows everything from its container. It is probably hidden somewhere around the nodes... Don't want to digg too deep there. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Quick look into source code reveals that it is allocated lazily:

```
public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {
    Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> es;
    return (es = entrySet) == null ? (entrySet = new EntrySet()) : es;
}
```

[Reference](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/HashMap.java?av=f#996)

> I think maybe there exist several threads operate entrySet then I
>   write a small tool with jvm_ti to print the threadID which invoke the
>   class below package java.util and find there is only one thread.

No, definitely there are `NO` threads involved (unless you explicitly created them)
If you want to debug it easily, set [watchpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568599/how-to-set-eclipse-watchpoint-to-activate-when-object-primitive-changes) on

```
transient Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet;
```

inside HashMap.

Comment: You're close :)

Comment: @rkosegi I agree that this method initialize entrySet, **but** I find before execute my first statement `HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();` this method was invoke and this should have nothing with my *map object*. Then this method has not been invoked.

Comment: @nailfei I'm pretty sure that this was just another HashMap.

Comment: @nailfei : yes it has not been invoked.

Answer (score 0):

entrySet is only an EntrySet instance, no place to initialize or add value into it,the most import function is used as an iterator in for-each,because it extends Iterable